# Script to see if user has logged off

Tags: bash, logs, users, administration

I have created this program to see if a user is logged on and it checks every minute.

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: mon user"
    exit 1
fi
user="$1"
until who | grep "^$user " > /dev/null
do
    sleep 60
done

echo "$user has logged on"
```

But my question is how can I modify this program to see if a user has logged off instead of logging in?

Thanks for any help provided! Much appreciated.

Comment: You could simply change `until` to `while`, but I do not think this is the most efficient or elegant method to be notified of user login activity.

Comment: Couldn't just use `-v` with the `grep` to and print out that user is not logged in? Of course, it won't tell you whether the user had logged in and then logged out, but would just tell you whether the user is logged in at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$#" -ne 1 ] && {
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) user"
    exit 1
}

user="$1"
grep "^$user:" /etc/passwd > /dev/null || {
    echo "There's no user called $user in this system."
    exit 2
}

who | grep "^$user " > /dev/null && sleep 60

echo "$user has logged out"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the secure log file (assuming you are just checking for remote login). The secure log file tells you when a user logs in and logs out. Also check the lastlog command as well as the wtmp and utmp files. They'll contain historical data for user logins.

Comment: /var/log/secure may not be set up in all distros. I think systemd has thrown away /var/log in favor of `journalctl`. I like the idea of using `who`\ `w` better as this will include those who are logged in non-remotely.